# Use regex and pymongo for extracts documents create in 2014

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo, python-re

I'm begginner to pymongo and i'd like find the count of the documents who have create in 2014 in 'update_date' and i'd like use the REGEX.
My code is :

```
exp = re.compile("[2][0][1][4]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")
pprint(list(col.find({"update_date": exp}, {"update_date": 1})))
```

the result find all documents in 2014 but i'd like count the documents in 2014.
My code :

```
exp = re.compile("[2][0][1][4]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")
col.find({"update_date": exp}, {"update_date": 1}).count()
```

and i've a message error :
`AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count'``
Can you help me ? Thank you.
Data exple :

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fa9a4db76fdd8d66273c643'),
 'abstract': '  A fully differential calculation in perturbative quantum '
             
 'authors': "C. Bal\\'azs, E. L. Berger, P. M. Nadolsky, C.-P. Yuan",
 'update_date': '2014-11-26',
 'versions': [{'created': 'Mon, 2 Apr 2007 19:18:42 GMT', 'version': 'v1'},
              {'created': 'Tue, 24 Jul 2007 20:10:27 GMT', 'version': 'v2'}]}
```

Thank you for your help.

my code is :
`exp = re.compile("[2][0][1][4]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")`

```
 col.find({"update_date": exp}, {"update_date": 1}).count()
```

my result : AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'count'

Comment: I don't know much about pymongo, but this may help: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.count_documents

Comment: There was an example from their tutorial section: `posts.count_documents({"author": "Mike"})` which is used to count the documents that matches a specific query.

Comment: I couldn't get this function to work.  my code : ' exp = re.compile("[2][0][1][4]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")  
col.count_documents({"update_date": exp}, {"update_date": 1})'  my message error : ValueError: 'session' argument must be a ClientSession or None.  I don't know why !

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution : a loop.

```
exp = re.compile("[2][0][1][4]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]")


tst = col.find({"update_date": exp}, {"update_date": 1})
li=[]
for i in tst:
    li.append(i)
print(len(li))
```